# how to show content as default in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, default, html

i have a ajax function with history support, but i want to load an page content from a link.

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<script src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabs-no-images.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="css-tabs">
  <li><a href="ajax1.htm">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="ajax2.htm">Second tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="ajax3.htm">An ultra long third tab</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="css-panes">
  <div style="display:block"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
      $("ul.css-tabs").tabs(
      "div.css-panes > div",
      {effect: 'ajax', history: true}
    );
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
/* root element for tabs  */
ul.css-tabs {
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

/* single tab */
ul.css-tabs li {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

/* link inside the tab. uses a background image */
ul.css-tabs a {
    float:left;
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-bottom:0px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    color:#777;
    margin-right:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    outline:0;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.css-tabs a:hover {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:#333;
}

/* selected tab */
ul.css-tabs a.current {
    background-color:#ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    color:#000;
    cursor:default;
}


/* tab pane */
.css-panes div {
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

and the  [jquery.tools.min](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69060927/New%20folder/jquery.tools.min.js)

i have three folder which contains ajax content.

i want, when a user go to the page index.html, they can see the content of any page (ajax1.htm or ..) as default content.
so my question is how to do it with my current code by adding extra code?

and please describe what to edit and where to place a external code or something.

Code from comments:

```
$(function() {
    var current_hash = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (window.location.hash != current_hash) {
            current_hash = window.location.hash;
            $('#content').load("ajax1.htm?page=" + current_hash);
        }
    }, 100);
});​
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and it may help us understand what you are looking for.

Comment: well i tried this code



$(function() {
    var current_hash = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(window.location.hash != current_hash) {
            current_hash = window.location.hash;
            $('#content').load("ajax1.htm?page="+current_hash);
        }        
    }, 100);    
});

Comment: that is odd.......... none of the members can help me!!!! it is really depressing..

Answer (score 0):

By the way i found a solution of my problem. i use jquery address master and that solved my problem. But another problem arrived, jquery conflict. 
i use 
mootools-yui-compressed.js (for fixed menu, which is only fixed on one axis)
jquery.address-1.5.min.js (for ajax address master function)
jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js (for ajax address master function)
jquery.js (for ajax address master function)

and the first (mootools-yui-compressed.js) and the last(jquery.js) conflict with eachother.
i tried

`jQuery.noConflict();`

but it did not work.
please help.